# I'm trying to create a daily countdown using AlarmManager in Android Studios

Tags: android, alarmmanager, countdown

I'm trying to make something where a set number will decrease everyday, even if the app is closed, and not active. For instance, if you don't open the app for 5 days, when you do open it, the number will be 5 numbers lower. I've been trying to use AlarmManager, but I can only get it to make a Toast and not run a function in the main activity. Here is my code...

Main Activity

```
private TextView mTest;
private Button mButton;

private int number = 100;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            scheduleAlarm();
        }
    });
}

public void scheduleAlarm(){
    Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 100000, 100000, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT ));
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is starting!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void subtract(){
    mTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    number -= 1;
    String numberString = Integer.toString(number);
    mTest.setText(numberString);
}
```

and Here is the broadcast

```
private MainActivity mMainActivity = new MainActivity();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

   mMainActivity.subtract();
   Toast.makeText(context, "This is bogus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: show your current code and attempts to fix the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily accomplish this using a Timer (https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

Follow this example:

```
long MINUTE_TO_MSEC = 60000;
long DAY_TO_MSEC = MINUTE_TO_MSEC * 60 * 24;
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask countdownTask = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        /* your function goes here */
    }
}
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,0,DAY_TO_MSEC);
```

This will run your code every 24 hours.

Comment: Thanks for the response James, but the reason I'm not using a Timer is because I want the "count down" to happen even if the app is closed or not active. I edited my question to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: Create a sharedPreferences variable and decrement that in the onReceive method or your AlarmReceiver. Then display the value of the sharedPreferences variable.

By setting `private int number = 100;` this will initialize the variable every time the class is instantiated.

Comment: Using the sharedPreferences worked great for counting down even when the app is closed! Thanks! However, the last thing I need is for the screen to update. I made a refresh button, which works, but I was wondering if there was anyway to have it update automatically every time the broadcast occurred.

Comment: sharedPreferences saves to disk right? Seems to have the potential to wear out the flash memory eventually...